# Extract object values from constructor function

Tags: javascript, object, oop

How can i extract these values from my object? Without writing 4 lines

```
constructor(product) {
    { title, imgUrl, price, desc } = product
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? Extract what to where?

Comment: `constructor({ title, imgUrl, price, desc })` or the way you’re showing it but add a `const`? It’s not clear what problem you’re actually having.

Comment: I mean this: ```const { x, y } = obj;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deconstruction works this way also:

```
constructor({ title, imgUrl, price, desc }) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var product = null;

function getProduct(){
  return this.product
}

constructor(product) {
  this.product =  { title, imgUrl, price, desc }
}
```

In the other class you could instance this class and call the `getProduct()` function

Comment: I’m not 100% sure I understand; in this example where do the properties you’re creating the object with come from? The OP’s question implies a product object already. Some additional code/context in the answer might help clarify.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).